# Log4j2 SMTP Appender on Java 11: javax.mail or jakarta.mail?

Tags: java, email, log4j, log4j2, java-11

I'm using Java 11 (Corretto 11), log4j 2.12.1, and jakarta.mail 2.0.1. My log4j configuration is using the SMTP appender, but I'm not receiving any emails. I do see the log statements in the file (when using the File or Console appenders). And also when using the exact same log4j config with Java 8, log4j 2.12.1, and javax.mail 1.6.2, I did receive emails. I can't use both javax.mail and jakarta.mail since there are overlapping classes (such as `com.sun.mail.util.MimeUtil`). It *does* work with javax.mail 1.6.2.

What is the recommendation for Java 11 + log4j2 + SMTP Appender? Am I stuck with using the older javax.mail 1.6.2 that's no longer maintained if I want to use log4j?

This may be a quirk in Eclipse, but when I look at the source of `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.MimeMessageBuilder` from log4j 2.12.1, the imports show `javax.mail.*`, but the javadoc for the `MimeMessage` class shows `jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage`.

[image: log4j2 source code showing use of both javax.mail and jakarta.mail packages.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are probably aware, the transfer of Java EE from Oracle to the Eclipse Foundation required a change from the `javax.*` namespace (in Java EE 8/Jakarta EE 8) to the `jakarta.*` namespace (Jakarta EE 9).

Since many years may pass until all libraries switch to Jakarta EE 9 and considering the fact that the switch must be done **simultaneously** for all Jakarta EE 9 technologies, Jakarta EE 8 implementations will probably get updates for a very long time.

Since Log4j is one of those libraries that did not migrate yet, use the [`jakarta.mail`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail) artifact, version 1.6.x from the `com.sun.mail` group. As you can see it still gets updates (latest version today: 1.6.7).

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think to look at the 1.6.x version of the jakarta.mail artifact.

Answer (score 3):

Since log4j2 2.18.0, an additional dependency log4j-jakarta-smtp can be included in pom along with log4j-core and log4j-api to make log4j2 use latest version of jakarta.mail instead of javax.mail

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-jakarta-smtp -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j-jakarta-smtp</artifactId>
<version>2.19.0</version>
</dependency>
```